# Let Lemp and Lamp stack send Access/Error log to Graylog2

Tags: syslog

I have two servers running, one with Apache and one with Nginx (Both Ubuntu based) they are allreading sending syslogs to my graylog2 node but i want Nginx to provide me with the Access log and and then the Lamp stack to provide me with the full error logs aswell.

I created a file called 90-graylog2.conf there is sending the syslog to my graylog2 node.

```
$template GRAYLOGRFC5424,"%protocol-version% %timestamp:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %app-name% %procid% %msg%\n"
*.* @10.0.2.13:1514;GRAYLOGRFC5424
```

I am just not sure what the correct way of doing this is.